# Insufficient free space: X extents needed, but only Y available

Tags: virtual-machines, lvm, vmware-workstation, capacity

I'm trying to extend a LVM in a Vmware Workstation 12 Pro CentOS VM. Below are the steps I am following and where I stopped because don't know how to folow from there:

1. Create the primary partition using `fdisk` command
2. Get partition table info using `fdisk -l`:

   ```
   # fdisk -l

   Disk /dev/sda: 85.9 GB, 85899345920 bytes
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 10443 cylinders
   Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disk identifier: 0x0001d929

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
   Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
   /dev/sda2              64        5222    41430016   8e  Linux LVM
   /dev/sda3            5222       10443    41940357+  8e  Linux LVM

   Disk /dev/mapper/vg_webserver-lv_root: 38.3 GB, 38277218304 bytes
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4653 cylinders
   Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disk identifier: 0x00000000


   Disk /dev/mapper/vg_webserver-lv_swap: 4143 MB, 4143972352 bytes
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 503 cylinders
   Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
   ```
3. Convert the partition to physical volume:

   ```
   # pvcreate /dev/sda3
     Physical volume "/dev/sda3" successfully created
   ```
4. Get the name of the volume to extend:

   ```
   # vgdisplay
     --- Volume group ---
     VG Name               vg_webserver
     System ID
     Format                lvm2
     Metadata Areas        1
     Metadata Sequence No  3
     VG Access             read/write
     VG Status             resizable
     MAX LV                0
     Cur LV                2
     Open LV               2
     Max PV                0
     Cur PV                1
     Act PV                1
     VG Size               39.51 GiB
     PE Size               4.00 MiB
     Total PE              10114
     Alloc PE / Size       10114 / 39.51 GiB
     Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
     VG UUID               qo4qm0-yTZc-TVzt-Ys0t-Ap2j-sH4X-rtMqPS
   ```
5. Extend the physical volume:

   ```
   # vgextend vg_webserver /dev/sda3
     Volume group "vg_webserver" successfully extended
   ```
6. Get the "free" space available:

   ```
   # vgextend vg_webserver /dev/sda3
     Volume group "vg_webserver" successfully extended
   ```
7. Get the info for logical volume:

   ```
   # lvdisplay
     --- Logical volume ---
     LV Path                /dev/vg_webserver/lv_root
     LV Name                lv_root
     VG Name                vg_webserver
     LV UUID                ayl9Ae-Y7nk-CVXG-c0G1-P4vx-wdlD-hEmXSO
     LV Write Access        read/write
     LV Creation host, time webserver.localhost, 2015-10-27 12:48:48 -0400
     LV Status              available
     # open                 1
     LV Size                35.65 GiB
     Current LE             9126
     Segments               1
     Allocation             inherit
     Read ahead sectors     auto
     - currently set to     256
     Block device           253:0

     --- Logical volume ---
     LV Path                /dev/vg_webserver/lv_swap
     LV Name                lv_swap
     VG Name                vg_webserver
     LV UUID                vwXfta-tGr0-kQFI-B2vF-L4gT-skE5-yb5qXA
     LV Write Access        read/write
     LV Creation host, time webserver.localhost, 2015-10-27 12:48:52 -0400
     LV Status              available
     # open                 1
     LV Size                3.86 GiB
     Current LE             988
     Segments               1
     Allocation             inherit
     Read ahead sectors     auto
     - currently set to     256
     Block device           253:1
   ```
8. Extend the logical volume:

   ```
   # lvextend -L+40G /dev/vg_webserver/lv_root
     Insufficient free space: 10240 extents needed, but only 10239 available
   ```

I got the error above and I don't know where to go from there and how to fix this, can any help me? What I am doing wrong and what is the logical explanation behind the issue I am running?

Note: I have read [this](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/nofreeext.html) but I am not sure how to undone every change I've already made and if this info is the path to follow

**UPDATE**

As requested here is the ouptut of the following commands:

```
# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               vg_webserver
  PV Size               39.51 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              10114
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          10114
  PV UUID               mwFIHY-mwwJ-b3uk-PkbP-7JXp-Vp2t-foCZtt

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               vg_webserver
  PV Size               40.00 GiB / not usable 1.38 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              10239
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          10239
  PV UUID               tWg4Oj-ZknB-mefb-Ggy9-V8Cu-C7S2-OvO5aU

# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_webserver
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               79.50 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              20353
  Alloc PE / Size       20353 / 79.50 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               qo4qm0-yTZc-TVzt-Ys0t-Ap2j-sH4X-rtMqPS

# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_webserver/lv_root
  LV Name                lv_root
  VG Name                vg_webserver
  LV UUID                ayl9Ae-Y7nk-CVXG-c0G1-P4vx-wdlD-hEmXSO
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time webserver.localhost, 2015-10-27 12:48:48 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                75.64 GiB
  Current LE             19365
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_webserver/lv_swap
  LV Name                lv_swap
  VG Name                vg_webserver
  LV UUID                vwXfta-tGr0-kQFI-B2vF-L4gT-skE5-yb5qXA
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time webserver.localhost, 2015-10-27 12:48:52 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                3.86 GiB
  Current LE             988
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think thare is some roundings at work that cause your `lvextend` to fail.

Try this: `lvextend /dev/vg_webserver/lv_root -l+100%FREE`

The above command will ask the system to allocate **all free space** to the selected logical volume, without asking for a specific size.

Comment: The command works and this is the output `# lvextend /dev/vg_webserver/lv_root -l+100%FREE
  Size of logical volume vg_webserver/lv_root changed from 35.65 GiB (9126 extents) to 75.64 GiB (19365 extents).
  Logical volume lv_root successfully resized` but where did the ~5GB goes?

Comment: Can you post the output of pvdisplay, vgdisplay and lvdisplay

Comment: Done, in the main post

Comment: It's all ok: lv_root was 35 GB, and after the added 40 GB it's at 75 GB. The other space is assigned to lv_swap (4 GB) and some is "lost" in rounding and decimal/binary conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You can run grab all free spaces: `lvextend /dev/vg_webserver/lv_root -l+100%FREE`

Following that you need to run:
In case of xfs: `xfs_growfs <partition>`
For ext4: `resize2fs <partition>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-l` option with number of available extents:

```
sudo lvextend  -l+10239 /dev/vg_webserver/lv_root
```

citation from `man lvextend`:

> ```
>    -l|--extents [+]Number[PERCENT]
> ```
>
> Specifies the new size of the LV in logical extents.
> The --size and --extents options are alternate methods of specifying
> size.  The total number of physical extents used will be greater when
> redundant data is needed for RAID levels.  An alternate syntax allows
> the size to be determined indirectly as a percentage of the size of a
> related VG, LV, or set of PVs. The suffix %VG denotes the total size
> of the VG, the suffix %FREE the remaining free space in the VG, and
> the suffix %PVS the free space in the specified PVs.  For a snapshot,
> the size can be expressed as a percentage of the total size of the
> origin LV with the suffix %ORIGIN (100%ORIGIN provides space for the
> whole origin).  When expressed as a percentage, the size defines an
> upper limit for the number of logical extents in the new LV. The
> precise number of logical extents in the new LV is not determined
> until the command has completed.  When the plus + or minus - prefix is
> used, the value is not an absolute size, but is relative and added or
> subtracted from the current size.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do this is:

```
#vgdisplay

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg2
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <2.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              511
  Alloc PE / Size       256 / 1.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       255 / 1020.00 MiB
  VG UUID               aY23Dw-zS2G-Ng0k-KwBr-G3mD-uQhk-VxNIpi
```

Look for "Free PE / Size". In this case 1020M. So do:

```
#lvresize -L +1020M "device"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vgdisplay    --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               cl
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <299.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              76543
  Alloc PE / Size       76543 / <299.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               wakdFZ-f1sR-3cNk-0bMH-VZaS-slgU-3MOOKt
```

i want extend   `/dev/mapper/cl-root`    to be 200 gb

my  `df-h  /dev/mapper/cl-root   50G  4.0G   47G   8% /`

`/dev/mapper/cl-home  241G  1.8G  240G   1% /home`

`/dev/sda1            976M  129M  781M  15% /boot`

how to do  thx

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/571779)